# How do you pass a function as a parameter of a function swift?

Tags: swift, function, parameters, closures

Looking to pass a function as a parameter (like an onCompletion) that will be invoked as part of the function call in Swift (similar to javascript closures). What's the best practice here?

Code:

```
func didFinishFunc(onCompletion: func) {
    func()
}

func onCompletionFunc()
{
    print("completed.")
}

func caller()
{
   didFinishFunc(onCompletion: onCompletionFunc)
}

// caller is called
caller()
```

Comment: Read the swift language guide. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: thanks for your elaborate response

Comment: I'm not going to waste my time writing an elaborate response to a question that would have been easily answered had you done your due diligence and read the language guide or googled around before coming here. There's a reason you have 3 down votes.

Comment: wonderful, thank you. Why respond to the question at all if it was a waste of time?

Comment: Because as a community, we don't like to down votes questions without explaining why we did. It gives the OP a way to improve their questions in the future

Comment: In that same vein, I posted this question not just to find an answer but to help developers coming from various other platforms and adopting Swift as novice users

Comment: Those people should also read the language guide, not search up ad-hoc solutions to mimicking features/patterns they've used in other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your function like this.

```
func didFinishFunc(onCompletion: () -> Void) {
    // your function implementation here

    onCompletion()
}
```

This function takes in a closure (sometimes called a callback or anonymous function in other languages) as a parameter. This closure has no parameters and no return value.

If you want the closure to have parameters you could do something like this:

```
func didFinishFunc(onCompletion: (String, Int) -> Void) {
    // your function implementation here

    onCompletion("foo", 5)
}
```

This function takes in two parameters a `String` and an `Int`.

If you want the closure to have a return type, change the type (above it is `Void`) after the `->`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Swift closure. E.g.

```
func didFinishFunc(onCompletion handler: () -> Void) {
    handler()
}
```

See [The Swift Programming Language: Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94).